# Anyone know what CMS is using 37signals to manage the site?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, content-management-system

I need to build simple site "one big page" like 37signals product's pages, and I was thinking about this.

Anyone have an idea? 
are they using Radiant or coding manually?

Answer (score 20, accepted):

[Signal vs. Noise](http://www.37signals.com/svn) is run with our own little engine called Blog Cabin. It just does what we need it to do. The [Product Blog](http://productblog.37signals.com) is powered by Typepad.

Our marketing sites are coded and maintained manually.

Answer (score 6):

I'm going to go out on a limb and guess that they rolled their own using rails.

Comment: Yeah doesn't really seem like they need a lot of the features a CMS provides, not does a CMS have a lot of the features they need.

Comment: Hell, it might be static HTML. Why bother with Rails to serve a half-dozen rarely changing pages?

Comment: 1,000 monkeys at typewriters updating HTML on the fly?

//whoops, I just described my job

Answer (score 4):

On the subject of publishing static content, Ryan's recommendation of Webby is good.  Another simple and good ruby static site generator is [Jekyll](http://github.com/mojombo/jekyll/tree/master) by Tom Preston-Werner.

Comment: Agreed, Jekyll is also sweet.

Answer (score 3):

I doubt they have anything as formal as a CMS.  I'm sure they rolled their own simple publishing mechanism that uses a few templates and a Rakefile.  That's what I would do, anyway.

If you're looking for something to help publish static content, I would recommend [Webby](http://webby.rubyforge.org/).  Mike Clark has a writeup on Webby, [Building Static Websites with Webby](http://clarkware.com/cgi/blosxom/2008/08/06).

Answer (score 3):

They have built their own blog engine and they call it "Blog Cabin". Here is a link to a blog post about when they made the switch from Type Pad: [The new(ish) Signal vs. Noise](http://www.37signals.com/svn/posts/37-the-newish-signal-vs-noise)

Answer (score 2):

And there's [Nanoc](http://nanoc.stoneship.org/) too, like Webby I think.

Answer (score 0):

I think webby is clever as well, although I really wish it had a built in mailer for sending form data by email.